# Inline functions mechanism

Tags: c++, inline

I know that an inline function does not use the stack for copying the parameters but it just replaces the body of the function wherever it is called.

Consider these two functions:

```
inline void add(int a) {
   a++; 
} // does nothing, a won't be changed
inline void add(int &a) {
   a++; 
} // changes the value of a
```

If the stack is not used for sending the parameters, how does the compiler know if a variable will be modified or not? What does the code looks like after replacing the calls of these two functions?

Comment: I'd say it should give a warning and optimize it out as long there aren't any side effects.

Comment: the compiler knows whether or not the function modifies memory.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but there are no parameters if a functions gets inlined. There's no function call. If you write `int a = 0; add(a);` after inlining it'll be just `int a = 0; a++;` and after further optimization just `int a = 1`.

Comment: Your `a` is stored _somewhere_ - either in memory or on stack of the caller of the inlined function. Compiler does what it sees fit with the stack of the caller to accommodate the inlined function's needs. After all, inlined function might use some local variables within itself. Compiler will put them on the stack of the caller.

Comment: The first one accepts a copy, so it becomes `int a = 0; int a_clone = a; a_clone++; /*Then discard a_clone*/`

Comment: I've just checked compiling both functions into assembly using `g++ -finline-functions -S q.cpp` and neither function gets inlined.

Comment: Checked that: @IgorPopov's right!

Comment: Adding -O1 to the command line removes the calls completetly.

Comment: @IgorPopov But they both get inlined on `-O1` and above.

Comment: @TAS The reason for the removal the functions is that compiler finds out that there is no any effect of invoking them. In case of pass by reference `add(int &a)` compiler would not remove it if variable `a` is used upon invocation of the function.

Comment: @IgorPopov Already knew that. But thanks anyway for explaining it.

Comment: @IgorPopov Maybe I misunderstood you, but optimization by removal of code that does nothing has nothing to do with inlining.

Comment: @PetrBudnik Indeed it doesn't have to do anything with inlining. My comment is just a notice of @TAS that `-O1` g++ switch removes the code.

Comment: @IgorPopov - I checked and the functions **are** inlined. Perhaps you are seeing that functions are also defined as out-of-line functions. The standard dictates that "*An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is used"*. Inlining means that this out-of-line definition is not called when the function is used. There is no call to either of those with `-finline-functions`.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think there is a stack ? And even if there is, what makes you think it would be use for passing parameters ?

You have to understand that there are two levels of reasoning:

- the language level: where the semantics of what should happen are defined
- the machine level: where said semantics, encoded into CPU instructions, are carried out

At the language level, if you pass a parameter by non-const reference it might be modified by the function. The language level knows not what this mysterious "stack" is. *Note: the `inline` keyword has little to no effect on whether a function call is inlined, it just says that the definition is in-line.*

At machine level... there are many ways to achieve this. When making a function call, you have to obey a *calling convention*. This convention defines *how* the function parameters (and return types) are exchanged between caller and callee and who among them is responsible for saving/restoring the CPU registers. In general, because it is so low-level, this convention changes on a per CPU family basis.

For example, on x86, a couple parameters will be passed directly in CPU registers (if they fit) whilst remaining parameters (if any) will be passed on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked what at least GCC does with it if you force it to inline the methods:

```
inline static void add1(int a) __attribute__((always_inline)); 
void add1(int a) {
   a++; 
} // does nothing, a won't be changed

inline static void add2(int &a) __attribute__((always_inline));
void add2(int &a) {
   a++; 
} // changes the value of a

int main() {

label1:
    int b = 0;
    add1(b);

label2:
    int a = 0;
    add2(a);

    return 0;
}
```

The assembly output for this looks like:

```
.file   "test.cpp"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $16, %esp
.L2:
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)
    addl    $1, -8(%ebp)
.L3:
    movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
```

Interestingly even the first call of `add1()` that effectively does nothing as a result outside of the function call, isn't optimized out.

Comment: I am curious, what compiler flags did you use?

Comment: I've been using `g++ -finline-functions -S test.cpp`, but that alone doesn't force inlining without using the attributes on the function decls.

Comment: The main reason I ask is that when I compile with anything above -O0, **all** of main gets optimized to nothing for me! (gcc-4.7)

Comment: Then why are you wondering that code that does nothing is not stripped?

Comment: Let's add doing  s.th. with `a` and `b`, will be back in a minute.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: Huh? If it does nothing, then in theory, it should always be stripped out. I am curious why he is seeing code emitted when I see it optimized to nothing (I expected the latter since the neither `a` or `b`'s final results are used).

Comment: @g-makulik: compile with `-O2` or higher if you want to test code emission. it doesn't make sense to test "code quality" or "optimizations" without it because then you are basically asking the compiler *not* to do many typical optimizations.

Comment: @EvanTeran Seems you're right, it's useless inspecting it this way.

Comment: @EvanTeran What do you mean? As far as I know, in `int main(){ for (std::size_t i_ = 0; i_ < 1000000000000; ++i_){}  return (0);}` GCC will remove the loop starting with `-O2` optimization. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ok, so this shows that, when the compiler is not performing optimisation, it does indeed use the stack for the tempororary parameter to `add1` (although it could also use a register). Of course, since `add1` doesn't have any side effects, WITH optimisation, it should be possible (and likely) that the compiler eliminates the entire function.

Comment: @MatsPetersson From http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html : _"Without any optimization option, the compiler's goal is to reduce the cost of compilation and to make debugging produce the expected results. Statements are independent: if you stop the program with a breakpoint between statements, you can then assign a new value to any variable or change the program counter to any other statement in the function and get exactly the results you expect from the source code."_ It the defined behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: @PetrBudnik: Yes, my point is that it shows that the OP's statement about "Inline functions don't use stack" is flawed.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: sigh, you are completely misunderstanding what I wrote. I *expect* things like your example to be removed with optimizations `-O2` and higher. I was advising to @g-makulik that he should test with optimizations *enabled* because during his original test, he did not. My whole point is that when testing code emission, optimizations should be enabled...

Comment: @EvanTeran Heh, I think, you misunderstood me first ;)... I addressed g-makulik's last line in his post and his compilation flags when I said _"Then why are you wondering that code that does nothing is not stripped?"_. There is nothing interesting in the fact that without optimization compiler does not remove it. And then you addressed me with _"Huh? If it does nothing, then in theory, it should always be stripped out."_ Yes, but with optimization on... Anyway, it's a misunderstanding...

Answer (score 0):

> If the stack is not used for sending the parameters, how does the
>   compiler know if a variable will be modified or not?

As Matthieu M. already pointed out the language construction itself knows nothing about stack.You specify inline keyword to the function just to give a compiler a hint and express a wish that you would prefer this routine to be inlined. If this happens depends completely on the compiler.

The compiler tries to predict what the advantages of this process given particular circumstances might be. If the compiler decides that inlining the function will make the code slower, or unacceptably larger, it will not inline it. Or, if it simply cannot because of a syntactical dependency, such as other code using a function pointer for callbacks, or exporting the function externally as in a dynamic/static code library.

> What does the code looks like after replacing the calls of these two
>   functions?

At he moment none of this function is being inlined when compiled with

```
g++ -finline-functions -S main.cpp
```

and you can see it because in disassembly of main

```
void add1(int a) {
    a++;
}
void add2(int &a) {
   a++; 
}

inline void add3(int a) {
   a++; 
} // does nothing, a won't be changed

inline void add4(int &a) {
   a++; 
} // changes the value of a

inline int f() { return 43; }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int a = 31;
    add1(a);
    add2(a);
    add3(a);
    add4(a);
    return 0;
}
```

we see a **call** to each routine being made:

```
main:
.LFB8:
        .cfi_startproc
        .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
        movl    $31, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        movl    %eax, %edi
        call    _Z4add1i        // function call
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    _Z4add2Ri       // function call
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        movl    %eax, %edi
        call    _Z4add3i        // function call
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    _Z4add4Ri       // function call
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

compiling with -O1 will remove all functions from program at all because they do nothing.
However addition of

```
__attribute__((always_inline))
```

allows us to see what happens when code is inlined:

```
void add1(int a) {
    a++;
}

void add2(int &a) {
   a++; 
}

inline static void add3(int a) __attribute__((always_inline));
inline void add3(int a) {
   a++; 
} // does nothing, a won't be changed

inline static void add4(int& a) __attribute__((always_inline));
inline void add4(int &a) {
   a++; 
} // changes the value of a

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int a = 31;
    add1(a);
    add2(a);
    add3(a);
    add4(a);
    return 0;
}
```

now: `g++ -finline-functions -S main.cpp` results with:

```
main:
.LFB9:
        .cfi_startproc
        .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
        movl    $31, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        movl    %eax, %edi
        call    _Z4add1i        // function call
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    _Z4add2Ri       // function call
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
        addl    $1, -8(%rbp)    // addition is here, there is no call
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        addl    $1, %eax        // addition is here, no call again
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Answer (score 0):

The `inline` keyword has two key effects. One effect is that it is a hint to the implementation that *"inline substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism."* This usage is a hint, not a mandate, because *"an implementation is not required to perform this inline substitution at the point of call"*.

The other principal effect is how it modifies the one definition rule. Per the ODR, a program must contain exactly one definition of any given non-inline function that is odr-used in the program. That doesn't quite work with an inline function because *"An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used ..."*. Use the same inline function in one hundred different translation units and the linker will be confronted with one hundred definitions of the function. This isn't a problem because those multiple implementations of the same function *"... shall have exactly the same definition in every case."* One way to look at this: There still is only one definition; it just looks like there are a whole bunch to the linker.

Note: All quoted material are from section 7.1.2 of the C++11 standard.