# why are C++ compiler synthesized functions (e.g. default constructor) inline?

Tags: c++

I know that compiler synthesized functions in c++, such as default constructor, copy constructor .etc are implicitly inline, but I am just curious about **why**?

and, what if the tasks these functions need to do are too complicated to be inappropriate to be inlined?

Comment: because it is faster? and synthesized functions can't be too complicated

Comment: @BryanChen: Not true, they might be complicated (consider a polymorphic inheritance hierarchy, with a few members, multiple bases, even some virtual bases...) Real inlining might not make them faster but slower.

Comment: I'd guess that might come from compliance with [tag:c](99?) historically (`struct` and `class` are just semantic variations on default member visibility)? Could be completely wrong with this, dunno ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first question is what does it really mean to be `inline`? The answer to that question has little to do with actual inlining, and more to do with the One Definition Rule. When the compiler generates code for an inline function it marks the symbol for the linker to know that having that same symbol in different translation units is fine.

With this in mind, the answer is quite simple. If the functions were not `inline` and the compiler generated them in two different translation units, linking both translation units together would cause a violation of the One Definition Rule that is outside of the reach of the programmer to fix.

---

It seems that the answer above is not clear enough regarding what happens when the function is not really inlined. From the first paragraph:

> When the compiler generates code for an inline function it marks the symbol for the linker to know that having that same symbol in different translation units is fine.

The compiler does generate a function symbol in each translation unit that uses that function. The linker will then use the mark (weak symbol) to discard all but one of the definitions from the program. In many cases compilers generate an out-of-line definition of `inline` functions even when the function code is actually inlined.

This is different from marking the function as `static` (internal linkage) as if it was marked as internal linkage, all of those definitions would remain in the final executable <sup>*</sup>

<sup>*</sup> There are some linkers that are able to figure out that different symbols are exactly the same and will remove duplicates, so it might merge `void f() { std::cout << "Hi\n"; }` with void g() { std::cout << "Hi\n"; }`. Linkers that do this can also fold all of the`static` functions together, but this is an optimization outside of what the standard mandates.

Comment: Also, `inline` (implicit or explicit) will hint at the compiler to inline, but won't guarantee it.  You need a compiler extension like `__attribute__((alwaysinline))` to guarantee inlining.

Comment: @SamCristall: I don't even think that particular attribute *forces* inlining, it just provides a much stronger hint. The intended use case is to cause the inlining of the function even when compiling without optimizations, but it does not guarantee that the function will be inlined in all cases. The *always* refers a bit more to the optimization level than to where in the program inlining will occur.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas _'I don't even think that particular attribute forces inlining ...'_ [As far as I have checked it recently with GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618075/inline-functions-mechanism/19618647#19618647), it actually forces inlining (it's even only possible to put the attribute on declarations, providing a plain definition with this attribute gives a compiler error). Using optimization options (e.g. -O2) might decide throwing it out completely for showing no effects though.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas clang definitely forces it, unless it's impossible (indirect branch or some other construct).  Clang actually doesn't even do inline cost analysis if `alwaysinline` is on, because that would waste compilation time (inline analysis is very costly.)

Comment: thank you for answering the first question. I do never have considered reasons about **One Definition Rule**. So, if this is the main consideration, what will the compiler do if these functions are too complicated? make them non-inline but static? making them static seems also eliminates more than one definition collision.

Comment: @KingsamChen: Compilers usually generate an out of line definition even for functions that are really inlined. This is needed because a program could take the address of an inlined function, and that has to have a definition. The function is marked as a *weak* symbol and the linker will discard all but one definitions. If the function was marked as `static` the linker would keep *all* of the definitions as those are not visible outside of the translation unit. Some linkers are smart enough to fold equivalent functions, but they need not do that.